# how to work with stopPropagation

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, function, stoppropagation

I have element with stopPropagation, but within that element I have another element which I need to be able to use for event. But because it's child element of the one with stopPropagation. It's not working. Is there some way to enable propagation on element within element with stoped Propagation.
Thank you...

Comment: Include your code for binding the event handlers.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you simply trigger the event programmatically on the other element?

```
$('#firstElement').click(function(e){
  e.stopPropagation();
  $('#anotherElement').trigger("click");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

By default many events bubble up the DOM, so the click handler you have will obviously affect parent elements - it seems like you'd have an easier time using e.preventDefault() rather than e.stopPropagation()

See http://css-tricks.com/return-false-and-prevent-default/ for a great explaination on the differences